# How to detect if a cli utility is killed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a cli utility written with some args:

```
if args.command == 'delete':
        response = delete_region(args.timestamp)
```

delete_region function does everything required which takes about 5 mins. If the user tried to kill the cli command using ctrl+c or some other process sends a `SIGKILL` during these 5 mins I want to perform some cleanup. How can that be achieved?

Comment: `SIGKILL` will be troubling, since you should expect the OS to terminate the process rather soon. `SIGTERM` on the other hand can be handled by a signal handler.

Comment: How about SIGINT? (Ctrl+c)